# enforce names of controls in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How I can enforce in compilation time that each control has Name property setted in xaml (wpf) ?
I need it in clcickable controls, like Button, CheckBox, ..., my custom clickable controls,.....

I thought about these options:

1. May be write some exe file that will be part of pre-build event of VisualStudio projects (or VS solutions)?
   This exe indeed will be small compiler, that willl indentify start and and ot each control, and verify that it has the "Name=" string within it ?
2. May be Code Analysis that is built in Visual Studio 2017 ?
3. May be [roslyn](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/03/20/10-questions-10-answers-on-roslyn.aspx) can help ?

Comment: Yes.
Every medium and big project need reporting on what controls the user clicked, what areas the user used.
This ability is for bug reproducing and for general analitycs of what features of the project user used.
To achieve it you need to subscribe to several events of several type of controls (buttons, checkboxes, ..). And then you will be notified that the user presse specific button. But if the button doesn't have Name, then indeed you don't get any information. So I MUST have Names of each buttons (and several other control types) setted in xaml.

Comment: So still the same question, how I can enforce developers in compilation time (build time) to set some property (Tag or Name) in xaml wpf ?